# How to Change color of selected section in bootstrap slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-slider

Hi I was using the same application which was demonstrated in one of the link [Change color of selected section in bootstrap slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844135/change-color-of-selected-section-in-bootstrap-slider). Even after i use the same, i am not able to proceed. Can you please see and let me know the solution where i have done the mistakes. I have downloaded necessary .js and .css files into my system and referring them in my html page. This slider i am using for a feedback kind of. Few questions will follow with 10 options from 1 to 10. When the user selects 1 to 5, the slider should show "red" color (OK) , when its between 6 to 8 " Orange" (Good)  and 9 to 10 is shows "Green" (Excellent) . Please find my below code and help me. Thanks in advance

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<link href="js/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="js/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
#score .slider-selection {
    background: yellow;
}
</style>

<script>
    var r = $('#score').slider()
        .on('slideStart', RGBChange)
        .data('slider');

    var RGBChange = function() {
        alert("called");
        if(r.getValue() >= 1 && r.getValue() <=5 ){
        $('.slider-selection').css('background', 'red');
        document.getElementById("lbl").value = r.getValue();
        }
        else if(r.getValue() > 5 && r.getValue() <=8 ){
        $('.slider-selection').css('background', 'orange');
        document.getElementById("lbl").value = r.getValue();
        }
        else if(r.getValue() >= 1 && r.getValue() <=5 )
    };
</script>

<input
    type="text"
    Id = "score"
    name="scoreSlide"
    data-provide="slider"
    data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]" 
    data-slider-ticks-labels='["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]' 
    data-slider-min="1"
    data-slider-max="10"
    data-slider-step="1"
    data-slider-value="3",
    data-slider-tooltip="hide"
    /><br>
    <input type="text" ID="lbl" />
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle (or something similar) link?

Answer (score 1):

The following code does what you asked. However, I don't think it looks great with the light blue handles/buttons.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
    <link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<input
type="text"
Id = "score"
name="scoreSlide"
data-provide="slider"
data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]" 
data-slider-ticks-labels='["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]' 
data-slider-min="1"
data-slider-max="10"
data-slider-step="1"
data-slider-value="3"
data-slider-tooltip="hide"
/>
<input type="text" id="lbl" />
<script>
var r = $('#score').slider()
    .on('slideStop', function(ev){
    var value = r.getValue();
        if(value >= 1 && value <= 5){
            $('.slider-selection').css('background', 'red');
        }
        else if(value > 5 && value <= 8) {
            $('.slider-selection').css('background', 'orange');
        }
        else if(value > 8 && value <= 10) {
            $('.slider-selection').css('background', 'green');
        }
        $('#lbl').val = value;
    })
    .data('slider');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```